# Overwrite file on remote server with psftp if it exists only

Tags: command-line, putty, file-transfer, psftp

I am a newbie with command line and PSFTP command line upload, I am used to FileZilla but at the moment, I am uploading some files with extension (`.js`, `.php`, `.txt`) to my remote server via PSFTP command line.

I've found out that PSFTP automatically overwrites the file without asking anything.

Now my question is: just like the `@Override` command in Java where the compiler gives you an error if the method you are trying to override isn't in the super class, is there a key word for this too in PSFTP, because I wanted overrides the file and if it doesn't exist, I want to cancel the upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such command/keyword in `psftp`.

---

But you can achieve this with WinSCP using its [`stat` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_stat). Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://user:pass@example.com/" ^
    "stat /home/user/file.txt" ^
    "put c:\file.txt /home/user/file.txt" ^
    "exit"
```

By default WinSCP aborts the script, if any command fails. The `stat` command retrieves attributes of a remote file. If the `file.txt` does not exist, the `stat` commands fails, and the [`put`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) never happens.

Learn more about scripting with WinSCP:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*